# Local Storage Exposed to Users

Tags: html, local-storage

Are the values of items stored using the localStorage API viewable by users? Just like cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Safari and Chrome's web inspector allows inspection of that data, yes. I'm not sure how other browsers handle it, but it's certainly not something you can depend on not being edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load the items to be displayed to users.

Just loop through all the items in local storage using Javascript as the page loads...

```
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var item = "";//array to hold string values for each key value
var key ="";//array to hold string values for each key name
for (i=0;i < localStorage.length;i++) {

    var count = 0;
    if (key != "" | key != null) { //or matches what you're looking for
      item[count] = localStorage.getItem(key);
      key(i) = localStorage.key(i);
      count += 1;
    }

 }

function load_table()
{
if (item == "" || item == " " || item == null) {
document.write("<div id=\"list_table\" style=\"display: block;\">");
document.write("<h3>You have no stored items.</h3>");
document.write("</div>");
}
else {
     document.write("<div id=\"list_table\" style=\"display: block;\">");
     document.write("<h3>Stored Items</h3>");
     document.write("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">");

     for (i=0;i < item.length;i++) {
          document.write("<tr><td width=\"33%\" valign=\"top\">"+item(i)+"</td>");
          document.write("<td width=\"67%\" valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left: 0px; text-transform: capitalize;\">"+key(i)+"</td></tr>");
          }
 }


document.write("</table>");
document.write("</div> <!-- end list_table div -->");
} // end if (item != "")
} // end load_table
</script>
```

In the html, you stick a div that can be shown or hidden, in an appropriate place.

```
<div id="items_table" style="display: none;">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
//alert("calling load_table");
load_table();
//alert("DONE calling load_table");
</script>
</div>
```

If they click a link, you can then display items_table that is populated during page load, and hidden.  So long as you don't have thousands of items to load, it loads quickly.

I can dig up a link to toggling the display between block and none for the style display property if you like.