# Loop Through localStorage Containing Keyword

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there a way to loop through localStorage in javascript or JQuery based on a keyword rather than looping through all of localStorage?  I know I can do

```
 for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)...
```

But I'd rather do something like

```
 $.each('localStorage:contains("keyword")')...
```

Comment: Do you mean the key or the value that should contain "keyword"?

Comment: The keyword should be contained in the key.

Comment: I think my answer to this [question][1] might be what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8265078/1054225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not directly possible to use DOM selectors for generic objects.

You could, however, create a little function that filters as per a passed function:

```
Object.filter = function(obj, func) {
    var res = {};

    for(var key in obj) {
        // filter out own properties (not length) that pass the filter function
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "length" && func(key, obj[key])) {
            res[key] = obj[key];
        }
    };

    return res;
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var filtered = Object.filter(localStorage, function(i, v) {
                                               // Simply speaking, '~' is the
                                               // same as checking for '!== -1'
                                               return ~i.indexOf("keyword");
                                           });
$.each(filtered, function(i, v) {
    // ...
});
```

Using this generic function you can build additional convenience functions like:

```
Object.keyContains = function(obj, contains) {
    return Object.filter(obj, function(i, v) {
        return ~i.indexOf(contains);
    });
};
```

Then to iterate `localStorage` the way you want is as easy as:

```
$.each(Object.keyContains(localStorage, "keyword"), function(i, v) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Does the trick.  Long way to go to avoid a For loop though. :)  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has an inArray() method and I think that's what you're looking for -

[JQuery inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

In your case, you probably need something like this ...

var index = jQuery.inArray("keyword", localStorage);

// do what you need to with localStorage[index] from here

Comment: `localStorage` is not an array because it has custom keys/values, not a zero-based indexing for keys.

Comment: Still not a loop.  There may be more than one localStorage item containing the keyword